# Image Load process issue on javascript

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, dom

Well I am facing very strange problem, see the following scenario.

When page loads it's shows an image and on page load event the following thing happening...

```
$(function () {

    LoadCrop();
});
var i = true;

function LoadCrop() {
    debugger;
    if(i == true)
    { 
        i=false;
    }   
    else
    {
        i=true;
    }

    $('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').resizable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            panelwidth = ui.size.width;
            panelheight = ui.size.height;
            //updateresize(QueryString.idflyer, this.id, panelwidth, panelheight);
            $("#<%=hndResizeWidth.ClientID %>").val(panelwidth);
            $("#<%=hndResizeHeight.ClientID %>").val(panelheight);  
        }
    });

    sleep(1);

    var initialH = jQuery('#<%=hndInitialHeight.ClientID %>').val();
    var initialW = jQuery('#<%=hndInitialWidth.ClientID %>').val();

    if (initialH != '' || initialW != '') {
        jQuery('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords,
            setSelect:   [ 10, 10, Number(initialW) + 10, Number(initialH) + 10 ],
        });
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords
        });
    }
}
```

As seen this code is working fine, but when I do other process link rotate image or crop image than image suddenly invisible.

SO, for checking the problem I was trying and suddenly notice that If I put 2 alert boxes than everything is fine. See following code where I just added simply 2 alert boxes.

```
function LoadCrop() {
    debugger;
    if(i == true)
    {
        alert('1');
        sleep(1000);
        i=false;
    }   
    else
    {
        alert('2');
        sleep(1000);
        i=true;
    }

    $('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').resizable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            panelwidth = ui.size.width;
            panelheight = ui.size.height;
            //updateresize(QueryString.idflyer, this.id, panelwidth, panelheight);
            $("#<%=hndResizeWidth.ClientID %>").val(panelwidth);
            $("#<%=hndResizeHeight.ClientID %>").val(panelheight);  
        }
    });

    sleep(1);

    var initialH = jQuery('#<%=hndInitialHeight.ClientID %>').val();
    var initialW = jQuery('#<%=hndInitialWidth.ClientID %>').val();

    if (initialH != '' || initialW != '') {
        jQuery('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords,
            setSelect:   [ 10, 10, Number(initialW) + 10, Number(initialH) + 10 ],
        });
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords
        });
    }
}
```

It's dificult to get the exact problem and solution...
:(

**EDIT#1**

Also I notice that if I remove following code block than it solve the problem.

```
    $('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID %>').resizable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            panelwidth = ui.size.width;
            panelheight = ui.size.height;
            //updateresize(QueryString.idflyer, this.id, panelwidth, panelheight);
            $("#<%=hndResizeWidth.ClientID %>").val(panelwidth);
            $("#<%=hndResizeHeight.ClientID %>").val(panelheight);  
        }
    });
```

Also other thing is that this all control is in user control, and this control is in update panel of .ASPX page, so if I remove it from update panel than also it solve the problem...

May be ajax make it late delay....
:(

Comment: can you make a fiddle ??

Comment: It's difficult coz it's with asp.net so , I can only put html part,

Comment: oh ya i see ...  no need of fiddle